# actorSelection does not respond when wildcard is used

Tags: scala, akka, actor

When I call `actorSelection` with wildcard and there's no matching actors I expect to get `ActorIdentity(None,None)` in response but instead nothing happens. Is it normal situation or am I missing something here?

```
class A extends Actor {
  val b = context.actorOf(Props[B], "test")
  def receive = { case x => println(s"Response: $x") }

  context.actorSelection("/user/a/test") ! Identify(None)
  // Response: ActorIdentity(None,Some(Actor[akka://sys/user/a/test#121958964]))

  context.actorSelection("/user/a/nothing") ! Identify(None)
  // Response: ActorIdentity(None,None)

  context.actorSelection("/user/a/x*") ! Identify(None)
  // Nothing happens
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and it works. Is it possible that your test code is wrong? Do you see dead letters?

Comment: @Christian, no, I don't see them in console output. What version of akka do you use? Mine is 2.2.3

Comment: I tested again. I have the same behaviour. I posted a question on the akka mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/qnp_DHpnKIQ I'm using 2.2.3, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug.

See: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3992

**Update:**
Looks like this is by design (see ticket comments) and no bug after all...

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking all the steps to clear it out.